# How can I get the date of the uploaded file in DRF serializer?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

```
class FileUploadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file= serializers.FileField(
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf', 'doc', 'docx'])])
    user = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo_Model
        fields = ("file", "user")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FileUploadSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['file'].error_messages[
            'required'] = u'Please provide an file!'
        self.fields['file'].error_messages[
            'blank'] = u'Please provide a valid file!'
```

This is my serializer for uploading a file. How can I get the uploaded date of the uploaded file?

Answer (score 0):

I'll add that into `Foo_Model`

```py
class FooModel(...):
    uploaded_on = DateField(auto_now=True)
```

or you can set that time when the file is uploaded ...

Comment: can you please explain the second method?

Comment: you can override the create method in the serializer and set in there the uploaded_on field

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances